# How to remove the thumbnail frame in Nautilus?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, nautilus, thumbnails

I mean the gray border around thumbnails in icon view.
The file `thumbnail_frame.png` is not present in `/usr/share/pixmaps/`, not even a nautilus folder.
I have Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.

Answer (score 1):

This is far from a good solution, but its the best I have found so far.  Because the feature this uses is apparently supposed to only be for speeding up development, I would hope that there is a better way. But I haven't found anything else that works for me. (in Nautilus 3.20.4)

Based on https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GResource.html , you can specify 'overlay' resourse directories which replace the default resources with the `G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS` environment variable.  With this you could provide a replacement thumbnail_frame.png that is completely transparent, effectively removing it.

Example:

`SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH` could be something like `/home/cristian/replacementIcons` but that's up to you.

Create `SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH/thumbnail_frame.png` as a 512x512 transparent image. (I'm not sure if the size matters, but that's what I tested.)

Then you can launch nautilus from the terminal with `G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS=/org/gnome/nautilus/icons=SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH/icons nautilus`

In order to be able to make this work with opening nautilus from anywhere, you can edit /etc/environment as root and add `G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS="/org/gnome/nautilus/icons=SOME_ABSOLUTE_PATH/icons"` at the end of the file.

Then reboot and the thumbnail frames should have disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Why create a file at all?

```
export G_RESOURCE_OVERLAYS=/org/gnome/nautilus/icons/thumbnail_frame.png=/dev/null
```